# How can I extend Picker with a custom initializer?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to get the following code to work:

```
extension Picker where Label == Text, SelectionValue == Bool {
    init(selection: Binding<SelectionValue>) {
        self.init("Bool", selection: selection) {
            Text("TRUE").tag(true)
            Text("FALSE").tag(false)
        }
    }
}
```

But get this compiler error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'TupleView<(some View, some View)>' to closure result type 'Content'

The goal is to be able to create a picker the following way:

```
@State private var value = false

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Picker($value)
    }
}
```

I understand that the compiler tries to infer `Content` from the caller of the initializer, but since I am calling an existing initializer and provide it with content, why am I still seeing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified what the `Label` and `SelectedValue` types for the `Picker` should be in the extension header, but not `Content`, so this initialiser is added to pickers with all kinds of content types. But you don't really want that, do you? This initialiser only produces pickers with this specific type of `Content`:

```
{
    Text("TRUE").tag(true)
    Text("FALSE").tag(false)
}
```

But we can't really name the type of that, because it's `TupleView<(some View, some View)>`, and opaque types can't be used like that:

```
// nope!
extension Picker where Label == Text, SelectionValue == Bool, Content == TupleView<(some View, some View)> {
```

One way to work around this is to wrap the `Text`s in `AnyView`s:

```
extension Picker where Label == Text, SelectionValue == Bool, Content == TupleView<(AnyView, AnyView)> {
    init(_ selection: Binding<SelectionValue>) {
        self.init("Bool", selection: selection) {
            AnyView(Text("TRUE").tag(true))
            AnyView(Text("FALSE").tag(false))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I feared that AnyView would have to somehow be involved. But I still cannot wrap my head around why Content cannot be inferred from `self.init`. I mean, if we moved this initializer to a function that returns `some View` and replace `self.init` with `Picker(...)` then the compiler wouldn't complain. Why does it complain here?

Comment: Because you are declaring an initialiser. An initialiser on a generic type is supposed to be able to initialise any kind of that generic type. An initialiser of `Picker` should be able to initialise `Picker<Label, SelectionValue, Content>` should work for ***any*** `Label, SelectionValue, Content`, while your initialiser only works for one specific kind of `Content`, `Label` and `SelectionValue`. You could still add this initialiser, but you need to say it in the header, what types this will work for. @bcause